# Check for event trigger from one script to another

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a script that consist of an event and a function that is triggered when this is called. Now I have another script. How do I check if the event from first script is triggered?

First script

```
public class MyEventManager: MonoBehaviour
{ 

  private static MyEventManager _instance;

  public static MyEventManager Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
                _instance = FindObjectOfType<MyEventManager>();

            return _instance;
        }
    }

  public delegate void OpenEventHandler(bool wasOpened);
  public event OpenEventHandler Opening;

   public void OpeningObj()
    {
        OpeningObj(true);
    }

    public void OpeningObj(bool wasOpened)
    {
        Opening?.Invoke(wasOpened);
    }
```

Second script

```
private MyEventManager eventMan;

private void Start () {
        eventMan= (MyEventManager ) GameObject.FindObjectOfType (typeof (MyEventManager ));

    }

private void CalledFromFunction()
{
  Debug.Log("Is Called");
}
```

I get the error -  `No overload for 'CalledFromFunction' matches delegate 'MyEventManager.OpenEventHandler'`

Comment: Your question is very vague. Where and why do you need to detect if the opening was invoked? There could be multiple approach to this problem but you should describe your issues clearly.

Comment: @jegtugado basically the first script is the Master script and I cannot make any changes to it. I can create another script to listen to the event - Opening. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Well your method doesn't have the correct signature. It has to take a `bool` as parameter ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use a singleton approach, you don't actually need the `private MyEventManager eventMan;` in the other class. You can get access to the manager from anywhere with the public static property you have declared ( `public static Instance MyEventManager`), so to get acces to the manager just use `MyEventManager.Instance`, since it's static it will be accessible from anywhere.

To react to some event the listener need to subscribe to the event. It's done like this:

```
public class ListenerClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        MyEventManager.Instance.Opening += OnOpening;
    }
```

It means whenever the `Opening` event is triggered in the manager, the `OnOpening` method of the listener class should be called:

```
    void OnOpening(bool value)
    {
        // do stuff when the Opening event is triggered 
    }
}
```

EDIT: my browser failed to load the second part where you have posted the second script and the error message.
You get the error because you have declared the event delegate as a function that takes 1 boolean argument and has no return value ( `void OpenEventHandler(bool wasOpened)` but in the second script you set the event handler to the method that doesn't have arguments, therefore it doesn't match the delegate signature.
You need to change

```
private void CalledFromFunction()
```

to

```
private void CalledFromFunction(bool value)
```

to get the method match the delegate.

Answer (score 0):

You got error `No overload for 'CalledFromFunction' matches delegate 'MyEventManager.OpenEventHandler'` because  `OpenEventHandler` is a delegate with `bool` type parameter. So method `CalledFromFunction` requires a bool type parameter.
Second script:

```
private MyEventManager eventMan;

private void Start () {
        eventMan= (MyEventManager ) GameObject.FindObjectOfType (typeof (MyEventManager ));

        browserOverlay.Opening+= this.CalledFromFunction;
    }

private void CalledFromFunction(bool value)
{
  Debug.Log("Is Called");
}
```